Getting Overflow Error in Excel when using Format() to format as date
I have a vba automation to concatenate some text but it's been giving me the "Overflow" error when changing the result to date in this specific file (works fine in others).
Function FormatAsDate(value As Variant, isDateColumn As Boolean) As String
    ' Format the value as a date if it's a valid date or a date serial number
    If isDateColumn And IsNumeric(value) Then
       ** FormatAsDate = Format(CDbl(value), "mm/dd/yyyy")**
    Else
        FormatAsDate = CStr(value)
    End If
End Function

I've tried to use less rows (down to 10 rows) and nothing. Could it be hidden formatting in my file? Please help!

When it fails what's the value of value ?

You should always be suspicious of hidden characters in untrusted data (think - user input, unknown input). For instance, I can't tell you how many times leading or trailing spaces cause errors, or unprintable characters copied in with copy/paste from web pages.

@TimWilliams:   : value : 10052026 : Variant/Double

@topsail how do I check for this further?

That value is too large to convert to a date. ? format(10052026,"mm/dd/yyyy") in the Immediate window also gives "overflow"

@TimWilliams hmm I have no idea where it's grabbing that number actually. The original column is formatted as Text so it has unformatted dates. I formatted and none of them match that one with the ones I selected.

Without the rest of the code and some sample data there's not much else we could suggest.

@TimWilliams I understand, but I got it to work. I had some scattered -ve values in some of the cells that only appeared when I manually formatted. I deleted them and the vba was able to process all the 9k rows. Thanks for taking the time to help!

Try something like this:
If value Like "##/##/####" then Return(CDate(value))
If CLng(value) > 40000 and CLng(value) < 50000 then Return(CDate(value)) ' 2009 - 2036
If value Like "########" Then Return(DateSerial(Right(value,4), Left(value,2), Mid(Value,3,2))
Debug.Print "Error..."

